# Where are the large icons in the Android Action Bar Icon Pack?

Tags: android

You can download a pack of Action Bar Icons from Google at [this](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) url:

Included are three different icon sizes, xhdpi (64x64), mdpi (32x32), and hdpi (48x48), but there are no ldpi icons. Shouldn't there be or am I not understanding something?

When you use the Android Asset studio and create icons for the Action Bar, it creates all four sizes, so, what gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As on per August, 1 there are [less than 2% devices](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens) with `ldpi` density. I don't think it has much sense to waste your time creating `ldpi` resources, as quantity of these devices will decrease with a time.

Comment: Actually current stats show about 10% of devices are ldpi, and I know about 14% of our app's recent users are on ldpi devices (mostly 240x320 size).  No one likes to deal with yet another size of images, not to mention small screen layouts, but you should think carefully about whether you're willing to cut out 10-15% of your potential market.  You might check out [Taylor Ling's Action Bar Icon pack](http://androiduiux.com/2012/09/03/action-bar-icon-pack-1-free-download/), he's done a great service making this available.

Comment: @PeterJeffe, it seems Google updated stats and now things looks differently.